# PyDev tab alignment in inline comments

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm sure there is an easy fix for this, but I've scoured the preferences and haven't been able to find an option with an appropriate sounding name.

Here's a simple example,  the top line isn't in the code, but there to illustrate every 4th character position:

```
#    #    #    #    #    #    #    #
a = 2     # something        two
b = "ab"  # something else    foo
```

Between "something" and "two" I hit `<tab>` twice, between "something else" and "foo" I hit `<tab>` twice.

My expectation is that using tab inside a comment would insert the necessary spaces to get to the next tabstop (the way tab outside of a comment works)  Instead, pressing tab always inserts exactly 4 spaces, regardless of the column you're currently in.

This doesn't happen in Eclipse inside a Java project, which leaves me to believe it's a PyDev thing.

Just to be clear, I expected that hitting tab twice on the first line and once in the second would produce:

```
#    #    #    #    #    #    #    #
a = 2     # something         two
b = "ab"  # something else    foo
```

Thanks in advance for what is almost definitely a very simple fix.

P.S. I was hesitant with tagging this with Python, if there's a user with edit privileges wants to untag it, I wouldn't be offended in the least.

Comment: For future readers, since I posed this question, Fabio was kind enough to add this functionality -- the applicable setting is currently under **Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Tabs -> Allow tab stops in comments?**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really expected in PyDev right now.

As a note if someone would want to implement that, the related place is:

org.python.pydev.editor.autoedit.PyAutoIndentStrategy.customizeDocumentCommand -- with tests at org.python.pydev.editor.PyAutoIndentStrategyTest.

This currently enters the case where "if (!contentType.equals(ParsingUtils.PY_DEFAULT))" where we don't handle expected tab-stops as we'd on code partitions (i.e.: org.python.pydev.editor.autoedit.PyAutoIndentStrategy.handleTab).

Comment: Thank you Fabio, both for PyDev and your response!